# grep or sed to compare data in two files

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have one data set and I need to locate the same data in other file and need to write the output in one file. File2 is not tab de-liniated.

My input files are
File1

```
481063383 
481063385 
481063405 
481063413 
481063414 
481063556 
481063557
```

File2

```
gi|481063385|gb|AGK00601.1| gi|482884784|ref|YP_007881957.1|;gi|525663574|ref|YP_008222546.1|;gi|525702257|ref|YP_008233983.1|;gi|526469531|ref|YP_008339768.1|;gi|493291875|ref|WP_006249566.1|;gi|153093868|gb|EDN74800.1|;gi|452086149|gb|EME02540.1|;gi|481063385|gb|AGK00601.1|;gi|523434386|gb|AGQ41023.1|;gi|523447581|gb|AGQ25466.1|;gi|526275739|gb|AGR75939.1|;gi|528826207|gb|EPZ02985.1|;gi|528876793|gb|EPZ27820.1|;gi|528877212|gb|EPZ28234.1|;gi|528878693|gb|EPZ29697.1|    100.00  100.00  183 0   0   1   183 1   183 1e-137    384
gi|481063385|gb|AGK00601.1| gi|472332995|ref|YP_007665270.1|;gi|472337367|ref|YP_007669641.1|;gi|505296972|ref|WP_015484074.1|;gi|472257232|gb|AGI31762.1|;gi|472261604|gb|AGI36133.1|  100.00  100.00  183 0   0   1   183 3   185 2e-137    384
gi|481063385|gb|AGK00601.1| gi|544866331|ref|WP_021280149.1|;gi|528822399|gb|EPY99332.1|    99.45   100.00  183 1   0   1   183 1   183 6e-137    382
```

Output

```
481063413 
481063414
```

something like this

I tried 
`grep -f file1 file2 > results.txt`

I tried with loop in shell scripting also but output is empty file.
How can I do this job?

Comment: How did you get that output from `file2`? It doesn't even exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding different numbers in two data sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118634/finding-different-numbers-in-two-data-sets)

Comment: Please do not post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118634/finding-different-numbers-in-two-data-sets) over and over.  Also visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for information on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @devnull..Sorry that was different question n for that question I even didn't get answer here but I solved it on my own. The major difference is it is not tab de-liniated, SO worrying. Sorry for making U trouble. Yep..I am new to this forum so I was uanble to post good questions. Thanks for advice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: In a previous incarnation of this question, `file1` showed *space*-separated tokens (rather than newline-separated ones); on the off-chance that this represented the real input, my answer applies.

If the search terms in `file1` are indeed space-separated, you must separate them with newlines instead for use with `grep`'s `-f` option
(also, if the search terms are literals, it's safer to use `-F` to perform literal searches); `-o` ensures that only matches are output (separated by newlines):

```
 grep -Fof <(tr ' ' $'\n' < file1) file2 > results.txt
```

Comment: Makes me wonder, a poor written question with 3 up-votes. `:)`.

Comment: Sorry it was not working. it is not giving the desired output. Instead, it is giving as such in file2.

Comment: @jaypal That is the beauty of SO.  _Anything can happen._

Comment: @Tulasi Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on how you get the output you have shown in your question, so assuming you just want the matched numbers from `File2`, you can do (using your input data from the question):

```
$ grep -of File1 File2 
481063385
481063385
481063385
481063385
```

If you only want unique occurrences then pipe it to `sort -u`.

```
$ grep -of File1 File2 | sort -u
481063385
```

Comment: @mklement0 Roger that! `:)` Did `sort -u` and saved a `pipe`.

Comment: @Tulasi What's not working? Can you update your question stating clearly how you get the output you seek?